# backbone.js hover on root dom doesn't work

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

Why the hover event bind on the root dom doesn't work? Though by default, i can put the `<div class="activity span"></div>` around the template and with a wrapper `<div></div>` outside, but it sucks.
Please help~  thx

```
ActivityView = Backbone.View.extend(
    className: "activity span"
    events: {
        "hover" : "toggleSidebarTrigger"   // doesn't work..
        "hover img" : "foo"                // works
        "click" : "bar"                    // works
    }
    template: _.template($("#activity-item-template").html())
    initialize: ->
        this.model.bind("change", this.render, this)
        this.render()
    render: ->
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()))
    toggleSidebarTrigger: ->
        this.$(".sidebar-trigger").toggle()

)


  <script id="activity-item-template" type="text/template">
      <img src="{{ photo.url_m }}" class="activity-media" alt="" />
      <a href="#toggle-sidebar" class="sidebar-trigger"><%= image_tag "plus_69x69.png" %></a>
  </script>
```

Comment: can you put a code on jsfiddle.net to share ?

Comment: It doesn't work in any browsers? Does it throw errors? More details please.

Answer (score 0):

```
ActivityView = Backbone.View.extend(
    className: "activity span"
    events: {
        "hover" : "toggleSidebarTrigger"   // doesn't work..
        "hover img" : "foo"                // works
        "click" : "bar"                    // works
    }
    template: _.template($("#activity-item-template").html())
    initialize: ->
        this.model.bind("change", this.render, this)
        this.render()
    render: ->
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()))
    toggleSidebarTrigger: ->
        $(".sidebar-trigger", this.el).toggle()

)
```

try this one..

Comment: i'd like to try this, but isn't `this.$(selector) == $(selector, this.el)`?